# TFS Upgrade from 2010 to 2012

Tags: tfs

We have upgraded to TFS 2012 (from 2010) and are having a few issues with our custom process templates.

On each project we get this message when navigating to the Backlogs page on the web access site.

```
This feature cannot be used until you configure it for this team project.
```

Clicking configure and running the automatic configuration page returns the following errors for projects which have had their process templates customized when they were on 2010.

```
[Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action 'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork' to the work item type 'Task' because the state 'New' does not exist.

[Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action 'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork' to the work item type 'Task' because the state 'New' does not exist.

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog/States. TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: 'RequirementBacklog/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: Active, Resolved.

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400506: This element defines the states for work items that represent Bugs or Defects. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types that are defined in: BugWorkItems. The following states do not exist in any of the work item types: Active, Resolved.

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400507: Each work item type must support an initial state value that matches one of the states defined in: BugWorkItems. The following work item types have initial states that do not include any states defined in the bug state configuration: Bug.
```

Other projects which were not customized do not return the errors and they upgrade with no problems.

Reading around the web I can see the problem is because of the custom templates, but their seems to be a few different options for fixing this. Has anyone had any experience of this and what would you suggest doing to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [ALM Rangers' Upgrade guide](http://aka.ms/ebooktfsupgrade)? There is an appendix (and tool) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

There are some guides on MSDN, basically, you have customised your template away from the TFS understands. For example, for it to be MSF Agile, you have "User Stories", if you have "Requirements" you're CMMI.

I upgraded our heavily customised template based on these guides:

- [Update a customized process template to access new features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms194972.aspx#add_categories)
- [New features enabled for Team Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms194972.aspx#add_categories)

This isn't really a good fit question for SO, as it is quite open ended and the list of things could be quite broad.

That said, if you take your current work items and add what it is looking for, perform the upgrade, then remove them and update the configuration after wards it should work OK. 
For example, add a "New" state to the start of your tasks upgrade, then edit the process config after upgrade to say your equivalent of "New" is the Start Work Trigger.